# Unable to ping my VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iptables

I've installed a VirtualBox VM from http://virtualboximages.com/CentOS+6.4+x86_64+LAMP+Server+VirualBox+VDI+Virtual+Computer.

My VM has access to internet, and I can ping the host.
I've set a static IP address in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Webmin is preinstall, and I can reach `http://192.168.1.14:1000` from the host.

However I'm not able to ping or reach my VM with SSH. Also, `iptables` is disabled...

I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said, it looks like you have bridged networking enabled for your guest since you can reach your webmin console.

Make sure you have the `sshd` service up on your guest OS.  If you do `netstat -tln`, you should see a list of the listening ports on your machine.  If you see port **22** on the list, then you probably have some sort of firewall preventing you from accessing your port.  If you don't see port **22** then you most likely don't have `sshd` running.  You should see something like `0.0.0.0:22` (or `:::22` for ipv6).

You can check your service by running `service sshd status`.  If it's not running, do the following:

```
service sshd start
chkconfig sshd on
```

Those lines will start the service and enable it to start at boot time.

As far as the ping, you may have ICMP requests disabled, which is done by default sometimes for public web servers to prevent DOS attacks.